# LoggerConfiguration() without a main method

Tags: serilog

Brand new to Serilog, I apologize in advance if my question has been answered before.

All Serilog configuration examples I've found imply that somewhere very early in the execution chain some code similar to the below one should get executed in order to make Serilog write the log.

In a regular console app, yeah, that works, I just add that code in Main(). However, I am writing a DLL, so there is no Main() method. I can't tell which method will get called first, so I can't add the code to a particular method.

So I'm pretty much stuck, unless I am missing something obvious. Could anyone help me with a hint?

Thank you

```
Log.Logger = new LoggerConfiguration()
        .Enrich.FromLogContext()
        .MinimumLevel.Verbose()
        .WriteTo.File("log.txt", rollingInterval: RollingInterval.Day)
       .CreateLogger();
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Logging pipeline setup is generally a concern of the host application that is using your library and not something you setup within the library itself.

If your class library is part of your solution together with the host app and you decided to use Serilog, your library would normally rely on `Log.Logger` having being setup by the host process that is consuming your library.

```
public class MyClassWithinMyLibrary
{
    private readonly ILogger _log = Log.ForContext<MyClassWithinMyLibrary>();

    public void MyMethod()
    {
        _log.Information("Doing stuff inside the library");
    }
}
```

If you are building a library that is going to be consumed by others (e.g. via NuGet) and you don't really know if they want to use Serilog, or something else, then you'd normally take a dependency on [`Microsoft.Extensions.Logging`](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.Extensions.Logging/) and require the user to provide an `ILogger<T>` instance in the constructor of your classes, or use a custom interface that you provide within your library to make the bridge between their logging system and your library's logging system.

In a more niche scenario, where you really want to use Serilog internally for logging within the library (perhaps because a non-.NET app consumes your library), then you can use a [module initializer](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/proposals/csharp-9.0/module-initializers), which is a method that is called one time when your assembly is used, and gives you the opportunity to execute initialization code:

```
internal static class ModuleInitializer
{ 
    [ModuleInitializer]
    internal static void Run()
    {
        Log.Logger = new LoggerConfiguration()
            .Enrich.FromLogContext()
            .MinimumLevel.Verbose()
            .WriteTo.File("log.txt", rollingInterval: RollingInterval.Day)
            .CreateLogger();
    }
}
```

N.B. Module initializers require you to compile your code with the C# 9 compiler. If you're using an older version, you can still use a module initializer but you'll need a weaving tool such as [ModuleInit.Fody](https://github.com/fodyarchived/ModuleInit) that can include the module initializer in the assembly for you.

Comment: Another option besides using Microsoft.Extensions.Logging when you don't know what logging library the consuming app might be using is to create extension packages, like MyLibrary.Extensions.SerilogLogging. This technique is covered by [Nick Chapsas' 7 Techniques for Better Library Code](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=viBfsaPT2g8). That makes it possible to allow for other logging implementations, while still making Serilog available.

Comment: I am building a Data Layer, and the goal is to implement its own logging, no matter if the host process has it enabled or not. I wasn't aware of ModuleInitializer attribute, it seems it might be the solution I am looking for. Thank you so much for your help, your answer is top-notch. Much appreciated.

Comment: +1 Obligatory mention of [LibLog](https://github.com/damianh/LibLog). But: if a lib is your helper in your app, then overwriting `Log.Logger` might solve a problem; however, I'd strongly advise against going down that road of assuming its a good idea for a random lib to [override the single global app's static logger instance](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/oldnewthing/20050607-00/?p=35413) - better to provide a controlled way to initialize your library and have them confront the forces to be resolved, than do magic behind the scenes - inevitably that will make a mess in testing contexts etc.